# Method delegation in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, reflection, delegation, message-passing

I'm writing a small framework for orchestrating AWS clusters and there are some common hierarchical patterns that appear over and over again. One such pattern is gathering a collection of instances into a bigger object and then delegating some methods down to all the instances directly. So instead of copying and pasting the same boilerplate code over and over again I abstracted it with the following pattern:

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    if not item in self._allowed_items:
        raise NonDelegatableItem

    def delegator():
        for instance in self.all_instances:
            getattr(instance, item)()

    return delegator
```

Is there a better way or pattern for accomplishing the delegation?

Comment: it's idiomatic to use `not in`, and instead of `item`, I would say `method`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`__getattr__` is called when the whole class hirarchy is traversed and the attribute is not found. So it is better to generate the method once and store it in the class. Then finding the method takes less time next time.

```
>>> X.a

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    X.a
AttributeError: class X has no attribute 'a'
>>> x.a
new delegator
<function delegator at 0x02937D30>
>>> x.a
<bound method X.delegator of <__main__.X instance at 0x028DBC60>>
>>> X.a
<unbound method X.delegator>
```

Here you can see the adaption of your code to do that:

```
class NonDelegatableItem(AttributeError):
    pass

class X:
    def __getattr__(self, method_name):
        self.check_method_name_is_delegator(method_name)
        return self.create_delegator(method_name)

    def check_method_name_is_delegator(self, method_name):
        if method_name not in self._allowed_items:
            raise NonDelegatableItem('{} can not be delegated'.format(method_name))

    @classmethod
    def create_delegator(cls, method_name):
        print 'new delegator'
        def delegator(self, *args, **kw):
            self.check_method_name_is_delegator(method_name)
            for instance in self.all_instances:
                getattr(instance, method_name)(*args, **kw)
        setattr(cls, method_name, delegator)
        return delegator


x = X()

x._allowed_items = ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Good point. I didn't think of assigning the method as well along the way.

Comment: Nice one. Shouldn't `__getattr__`'s call to `check_method_name_is_delegator` be omitted so a non-delegatable attribute is not looked up again (someone could `catch` the `NonDelegatableItem` via an `except AttributeError` after all)? And the second call could be put outside the `delegator` with an `except NonDelegatableItem: def delegator(self, *args, **kw): raise NonDelegatableItem(...` so the delegatability is only checked once.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Sounds reasonable. You can create a new answer with this. We can discuss it afterwards.

Comment: @User Hm, StackOverflow should have a github-ish "fork answer" option ;) Actually I spoke to soon: your `setattr(cls, method_name, delegator)` already takes care of preventing another call to `__getattr__` (I confused it with the always-called `__getattribute__`), and by splitting off the `check_method_name_is_delegator`-check in `def delegator` one takes away the option to dynamically modify the `_allowed_items`. So the only remaining suggestion would be omitting `__getattr__`'s call to `check_method_name_is_delegator`, though that slightly increases performance for non-delegators...

Answer (score 14):

I've been researching on this and found two solutions. Use a decorator to change the class and create the delegators, or using descriptors for the delegators. I started with the first and then evolve to the second which I like more, so I will start by it. Both can be found here: https://gist.github.com/dhilst/7435a09b4419da349bb4cc4ae855a451 with doctests :)

-- Edit --

For anybody interested I made this a library: https://pypi.org/project/delegateto/

There were bugs in gist implementation, people contributed to this on github, the pypi project is updated, gist not. I strongly recommend you to use pypi version.

## Using descriptors

Descriptors are things that can be getted and setted. In this case we are interested in the gettable ability of descriptors. The delegate descriptor defined like this

```py
class DelegateTo:
    def __init__(self, to, method=None):
        self.to = to
        self.method = method
    def __get__(self, obj, objecttype):
        if self.method is not None:
            return getattr(getattr(obj, self.to), self.method)

        for method, v in obj.__class__.__dict__.items():
            if v is self:
                self.method = method
                return getattr(getattr(obj, self.to), method)
```

And is used like this

```py
class Foo:
    upper = DelegateTo('v')
    __len__ = DelegateTo('l')
    __iter__ = DelegateTo('l')
    def __init__(self, v, l):
         self.v = v
         self.l = l
```

To call a descriptor simply call the method `Foo('hello').upper()`. Magic methods also works `len(Foo('', [1,2,3,4]))` returns 4. The gist link above has a more powerful implementation but the basics is the same.

## Using decorators

Everytime that you need to change a class behavior in an repetitive way, a decorator is a candidate. In this case the decorator will call `setattr` at the class to create the delegators.

```py
def delegate(to, *methods):
    def dec(klass):
        def create_delegator(method):
            def delegator(self, *args, **kwargs):
                obj = getattr(self, to)
                m = getattr(obj, method)
                return m(*args, **kwargs)
            return delegator
        for m in methods:
            setattr(klass, m, create_delegator(m))
        return klass
    return dec
```

The usage is also simple, just decorate the class, as many times you want. The decorator will modify the class inplace so the same class is returned.

Here is a usage

```py
@delegate('v', 'upper', 'lower')
class Foo:
   def __init__(self, v):
       self.v = v
```

And the call of the delegated method is also transparent `Foo('hello').upper()`. I prefer the second one because it seems more idiomatic for me. The decorator has an advantage to support multiple methods but this is implementable on the descriptor form too.

Again, I really recommend that you see the gist: https://gist.github.com/dhilst/7435a09b4419da349bb4cc4ae855a451 there are tons of examples in the docstring. Just modify them and execute the scripts to play around.

-- Edit --

For any body interested, I make this a pip package https://pypi.org/project/delegateto/

-- Edit --

There were bugs in gist implementation, people contributed to this on github, the pypi project is updated, gist not. I strongly recommend you to use pypi version.

Regards