# What is __getattr__ order in the attribute lookup chain?

Tags: python-2.7, attributes, descriptor, getattr, name-lookup

So in order to get rid of some boilerplate I opted to implement `__getattr__` for delegating some method calls. The problem is that I also have a descriptor in the attribute lookup chain and they are not interacting as I expected. Here's the code:

```
class C(object):
    attr = Descriptor()

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        # just returns a method for all items that match
        # a certain pattern
```

Here's the problem. All the Python docs mention that `__getattr__` only gets called after the usual lookup chain fails but in this case `__getattr__` is always getting called ahead of `attr`.

So what is the proper way to have both a descriptor and `__getattr__` play nice with each other?

Here's what I'm observing:

```
a = C()
a.attr # goes to __getattr__ instead of C.attr.__get__
```

Issue solved. It turns out if there is an exception that is thrown from a descriptor then the lookup jumps to `__getattr__`.

Comment: Which error is thrown? I woud like to know that.

Comment: Any attribute lookup error. If you're already inside a descriptor's `__get__` method and an attribute lookup exception is thrown on anything inside the method then the lookup continues with `__getattr__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but in this case `__getattr__` is always getting called ahead of `attr`

Sorry, I do not understand.

```
>>> class C(object):
    attr = property(fget = lambda self: 5)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        # just returns a method for all items that match
        # a certain pattern

    return item

>>> C().x
'x'
>>> C().attr # attr.__get__ is called, not __getattr__
5
```

Could you specify what 'play nice with each other' means?
A way to play nicely as I understand it: [Method delegation in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961806/method-delegation-in-python/21966266)