# How to automatically delegate unimplemented methods to a different class?

Tags: python

I have a `class A` which implements method `x()` and `y()` but I also have a `class B` which implements method `z()`. Assuming there is a base `AbstractA` class. how can I detect any calls on `class A` which aren't implemented e.g. `z()` and forward them to `class B`? Please note that I can't have `A` inherit from `B` due to framework plumbings i.e.,

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod   

class AbstractA(ABC):
   # some magic for catching unimplemented method calls e.g. z
   # and forward them to B's. Here I have access to instances of
   # B e.g. context.b.z()
   
   @abstractmethod
   def x():
     pass

   @abstractmethod
   def y():
     pass

class A(AbstractA):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  def x():
    print('running x()')

  def y():
    print('running y()')

class B:
  def __init__(some plumbing args):
     super().__init__(some plumbing args) 

  def z():
     print('running z()')
 
a = A()
a.x()
a.y()
a.z()
```

To give a bit of context on this use-case, I have a multi-layered architecture with a data access layer (DAL) and then a service application layer (SAL). The DAL is a collection of DAOs that take care of wrapping all database access use-cases. The SAL builds on top of the DAL and mash ups DAL's data plus business application logic.

For example, a `PersonDao` implementation and a `PersonService`. `PersonService` will call `PersonDao` to build the business logic API but some times client code may request `PersonService` to find a person by id which is implemented in `PersonDao` directly. Therefore, instead of explicitly implementing a pass through service method for each DAO method, have this pass through or delegation automated on the abstract base level of `PersonService` so that if you do `person_service.find_by_id(3)` it will go straight to `PersonDao#find_by_id(id)`'s effectively making the service implementation a facade to the underlying DAOs.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961806/method-delegation-in-python

Comment: Do you know the classes/methods to delegate to ahead of time (i.e. statically)?

Comment: @ChrisGS yes I do, their interfaces are defined in an abstract class `AbstractDao` and each Dao implementation e.g., `PersonDao`

Comment: `B.z` should expect an instance of `B` as its first argument (or is `z` a static method?). In general, you can't "delegate" a call to `a.z` to a function that may have no idea what to do with an instance of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from inspect import isfunction

class AbstractA(ABC):
    # some magic for catching unimplemented method calls e.g. z
    # and forward them to B's. Here I have access to instances of
    # B e.g. context.b.z()

    @abstractmethod
    def x(self):
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def y(self):
        pass

class A(AbstractA):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.checker = 'value in A'

    def x(self):
        print('running x()')

    def y(self):
        print('running y()')

class B:
    def __init__(self, some_plumbing_args = None):
        self.checker = 'value in B'
    
    def z(self):
        print('running z()')
        print(self.checker)
```

Get functions' name only in `class B`.
Bind the functions to `class A`.

```
functions_name_of_A = set(name for name, obj in A.__dict__.items() if isfunction(obj) == True and not name.startswith('__'))
functions_name_of_B = set(name for name, obj in B.__dict__.items() if isfunction(obj) == True and not name.startswith('__'))
functions_name = functions_name_of_B - functions_name_of_A

for name in functions_name:
    setattr(A, name, B.__dict__[name])
```

The value only in `class A` is showed by `z()`.

```
a = A()
a.x()
a.y()
a.z()
```

```
>>> running x()
>>> running y()
>>> running z()
>>> value in A
```

The value only in `class B` is showed by `z()`, too.

```
b = B()
b.z()
```

```
>>> running z()
>>> value in B
```